# How to use lombok's @Tolerate on a constructor

Tags: java, lombok

The `@Tolerate` annotation is an experimental feature in `lombok` where the target type is either a Method or a Constructor. The lombok [website](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Tolerate) mentions as:

> Any method or constructor can be annotated with @Tolerate and lombok will act as if it does not exist.

It states an example for a setter method:

```java
@Setter
private Date date;

@Tolerate
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = Date.valueOf(date);
}
```

In the above example **if we had NOT added** `@Tolerate`, then lombok would **NOT** generate `setDate(Date date)` because a method of the same name already exists (even though parameter type is different).
So, how it works for a method is clear from this example.

But I am not able to understand how this annotation is to be used for a constructor.

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class One {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // adding @Tolerate here does nothing. 
    public One(int a, int b) {
    }
}
```

In the above code, lombok would generate an all argument constructor even if another constructor with the same number of parameters but different type exist.

So, how can we use `@Tolerate` in the context of a constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Data`, `@Value` and `@Builder` annotations create constructors (a constructor for all required arguments in the `@Data` case, and a constructor for all arguments in the `@Value` and `@Builder`case). However, they do these only, if no other constructors exist. If you create your own constructor(s), `@Data`, `@Value` and `@Builder` will not create their constructors, unless you annotate your own constructor(s) with `@Tolerate`.

In a nutshell, `@Tolerate` on a constructor only makes a difference, if you use it together with `@Data`, `@Value` or `@Builder`. It has no effect, if you use it with `@NoArgConstructor`, `@AllArgsConstructor` or `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, just like Gautham noticed.

Example:

```
@Value
public class Main {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    
    @Tolerate // Now the allArgsConstructor will be created. If you omit the annotation, no allArgsConstructor will be created.
    public Main(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lombok [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor) for `AllArgConstructor` contradicts to what you say `Unlike most other lombok annotations, the existence of an explicit constructor does not stop these annotations from generating their own constructor. This means you can write your own specialized constructor, and let lombok generate the boilerplate ones as well`

Comment: @RomanKonoval I assume you understood the doc in a slightly different way. It is not specific to `@AllArgConstructor`. The statement is for all three constructor annotations. It says that,for example, `@Getter` will not generate if we have already specified a getter method of the same name. But in case of these constructor annotations, lombok would also generate a constructor. But this is want the last sentence in the doc says (which you missed to add `If a conflict arises (one of your constructors ends up with the same signature as one that lombok generates), a compiler error will occur.`

Comment: @RomanKonoval Also what @Mario was trying to explain was the `@Data` would apply the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` only if there are no explicit constructors are present. Similarly is the case for `@Value`. The doc for `@Value` says `Also, any explicit constructor, no matter the arguments list, implies lombok will not generate a constructor`. In both these cases the constructor annotation is not applied. If it had applied, then as you said lombok would also generate the constructor. And this is what happens when you add `@Tolerate`, `@Data` and `@Value` would ignore explicit constructor.

Comment: @GauthamM The last sentence says about conflict but in the example above there is no conflict. I've check and the answer is correct in the sense that lombok does behave this way, but I still see the contradiction of the behaviour and the documentation. To me it looks like a bug in the documentation.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, thanks for the comment. I edited my answer, and tried to make my point clearer.

Comment: @RomanKonoval May be my second comment explains that. the args annotation is not applied by `@Data` and `@Value` if an explicit constructor is present.

Comment: Now I see what I've missed. The javadoc for `@Value` does not have this and is misleading but the [complete](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) documentation says this (note the part starting from except): `@Value is shorthand for: final @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode @AllArgsConstructor @FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) @Getter, except that explicitly including an implementation of any of the relevant methods simply means that part won't be generated and no warning will be emitted`

Comment: @RomanKonoval Yes, I think it is not in the doc when you see the code only available in website. They should have added that.

Comment: @MarioVarchmin Maybe you can add `@Builder` case as well in the answer. It also adds a private `@AllArgsConstructor` only when no explicit constructor is present. here also `@Tolerate` would be useful.